# three div next to each other, the middle should be 100%

Tags: html, css

I want to do the following, but I might cant express myself well:

```
LEFT CONTENT |     IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE     | RIGHT CONTENT |
```

-

```
LEFT CONTENT |                    IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE                 | RIGHT CONTENT |
```

-

```
LEFT    |                 | RIGHT   |
CONTENT | IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE | CONTENT |
```

-
so, the left content - right content must have a fixed width. When I shrink the screen and IMAGEIMAGEIMAGE has no space, then LEFT CONTENT and RIGHT content should be line broken.

```
<div style="background-color: yellow;">
<div id="a">break me new lines</div>
<div id="b"><img src="http://www.hdwallpapers3g.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Images-6.jpg" height="60" width="300"></div>
<div id="c">break me new lines</div>
</div>

#a
{
    float: left;  
    background-color: red; 
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 140px;
}

#b
{
    float: left; 
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

#c
{
    float: left; 
    background-color: blue; 
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 140px;
}

div
{
    height: 60px;
}
```

here is [what I tried](http://jsfiddle.net/hAXHF/5/)

Two problems:

1. the whole content wont fill the 100% width, as you can see
2. the image goes under the 3. column

Comment: remove max-width from your css

Comment: Have you tried using a framework such as bootstrap3? http://getbootstrap.com/. You can use their fully responsive grid system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I was trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/YkndN/

```
<div>
<div style="display: table-cell; background-color: red; width: 48%;">
    left l l l lllll l l lllll ll
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell; width: 2%; background-color: blue; text-align: center;">
    centeredwhichmustcausebreak
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell; background-color: green; width: 48%; text-align: right;">
    right rrrrr r r r rrrrrrrrr rrr
</div>
</div>
```

state closed :)

Answer (score 3):

You should remove `max-width` from `#a` and `#c`, then add `width` to the `img` tag inside `#b`.

```
#a
{
    float: left;  
    background-color: red; 
    width: 25%;    
}

#b
{
    float: left; 
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

#c
{
    float: left; 
    background-color: blue; 
    width: 25%;    
}

div
{
    height: 60px;
}
#b img{
    width:100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/hAXHF/6/)

Comment: that looks OK. But I dont want the middle image stretching :)

Comment: then remove this `#b img{
    width:100%;
}` from your css

Comment: Then the img again goes under the 3. column, and no line break will happen

Comment: are you want it above the column

Comment: yes, but not just changing the Z value, I want that image make linebreak the text in the left and right columns

Answer (score 1):

1. You should remove max-width of #a and #c or you can use the media queries for the responsive http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
2. add

   #b img{
        width: 100%;
      }

I think it will better to use a CSS framework for the responsive and accelerate the developpement like the grid system of `twitter bootstrap`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid